# Wordpress page elements not responding to click to edit

Tags: javascript, wordpress, admin, backend

Wordpress as become unresponsive over the last few weeks when we want to edit page elements. It's as if there is a layer between the mouse and button which is not allowing us to trigger the edit button.

[image: Page elements to edit]

Comment: How you conclude this, have you write any test? If there is a layer (overlay may be) then you can easily catch that through browser console/debug tool

Comment: I have been through the developer console but nothing standing out.

Comment: right click on the target and select inspect then take a screenshot of the browser debugger tool and the element you clicked and analyze that at debugger is it pointing to the right DOM or not